# $\frac{1}{A}e^{(c-\varepsilon)\sqrt{n}} < g(n) < e^{c\sqrt{n}}$ implies $\log{g(n)} \sim c\sqrt{n}$.

Tags: asymptotics, epsilon-delta

The following is from a research paper:
Suppose $g(n) < e^{c\sqrt{n}}$ for some constant $c$ and for all integers $n \ge 1$. Suppose, in addition that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a constant $A > 0$ such that $g(n) > \frac{1}{A}e^{(c-\varepsilon)\sqrt{n}}$. They concluded that $\log{g(n)} \sim c\sqrt{n}$. I can see that for a fixed $\varepsilon > 0$,

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{A}e^{(c-\varepsilon)\sqrt{n}} &< g(n) < e^{c\sqrt{n}} \\
(c-\varepsilon)\sqrt{n} - \log A &< \log g(n) < c\sqrt{n} \\
\frac{(c-\varepsilon)}{c} - \frac{\log A}{c\sqrt{n}} &< \frac{\log g(n)}{c\sqrt{n}} < 1
\end{align*}
$$
As $n \rightarrow \infty$, the left term in the inequality goes to $\frac{c-\varepsilon}{c}$. I know this can be made arbitrarily close to 1 by taking $\varepsilon$ arbitrarily small, but because of the dependence of the constant $A$ on epsilon, I feel like I can't conclude anything.
Some clarification will be appreciated.

Comment: Is $c$ assumed to be nonzero? Also, does $g(n)>\frac{1}{A}e^{(c-\varepsilon)\sqrt{n}}$ hold for all $n\geq 1$? I'm sorry if these questions seem dumb, I just really want to make sure that I interpreted the post correctly.

Comment: Yes, $c$ is nonzero, and the inequality also holds for all $n\ge 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, let's extract the core question here:

> Suppose that there exist two functions $f,\delta\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \delta(n)=0$ and, for every $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $A_\varepsilon$ such that
> $$
> 1-\varepsilon - A_\varepsilon\cdot \delta(n) \leq f(n) \leq 1 \tag{1}
> $$
> Then do we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=1$?

Note that your question correcponds to $f(n) = \frac{\log g(n)}{c\sqrt{n}}$; and the conclusion is exactly the definition of $\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty}$.
Fix any $\varepsilon>0$. From (1), we get (taking $n\to\infty$) that
$$
\lim\!\inf_{n\to\infty} f(n) \geq 1-\varepsilon \tag{2}
$$
Since this holds for every $\varepsilon>0$, we can take the limit as $\varepsilon \searrow 0$ to get
$$
\lim\!\inf_{n\to\infty} f(n) \geq 1 \tag{3}
$$
and since $f(n) \leq 1$ by (1), we get $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n) = 1$.

Comment: Did you mean $f(n) \le 1$ in you last sentence? Also, as $\varepsilon$ goes to 0, what if $A_{\varepsilon}$ grows in such a way that $\delta(n)A_{\varepsilon}$ does not got to 0 anymore?

Comment: @fwd good catch, that was indeed $f(n) \leq 1$. Regarding the last comment: it is indeed a bit confusing, but this cannot happen here as $\varepsilon$ and $n$ are not coupled. You can first look at $n\to\infty$ for fixed $\varepsilon$, then take $\varepsilon \to 0$. In terms of quantitative bounds, this will end up meaning that in the $\varepsilon,N$ definition of a limit the $N$ around which you get close to the limit (where the asymptotics "kick in") can be a very large function of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. By $\varepsilon$ and $n$ are not coupled, do you mean they're $\epsilon$ is not a function of $n$ and vice versa? Basically I want to understand precisely when it is legal to perform 2 limits in succession without worrying about one interfering with the other.

Comment: Yes: $\varepsilon$ is a "free variable", not a function of $n$. @fwd